# Getting an error for this simple code I'm using. I bet the solution is very simple but I can't seem to find an answer online. Thank you in advance

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence, dereference

This is the code I tried to run (have a C assignment I'm working on but this is just to help me understand the syntax with pointers in C.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct cow{
  int moo;  
};

void newm(struct cow *a){
    *a.moo = 5;
}

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    printf("Hello world");
    struct cow a;
    newm(&a);
    printf("hallo %i", a.moo);
    

    return 0;
}
```

When running the code I get the following error message:

```
gcc /tmp/2RZ9WOHWdH.c -lm
/tmp/2RZ9WOHWdH.c: In function 'newm':
/tmp/2RZ9WOHWdH.c:9:9: error: 'a' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
    9 |     *(a).moo = 5;
      |         ^
      |         ->
```

Comment: The compiler tells you what to do - why don't you try following its suggestion?

Comment: The error message is explicit: you just have to write `a->moo = 5;`, which is syntactic sugar (and idiomatic way) for `(*a).moo = 5;`

Comment: According to the [rules of operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression `*a.moo` is equivalent to `*(a.moo)`. You probably intended to write `(*a).moo`, which is equivalent to `a->moo`.

Comment: @UnholySheep my bad still learning my ways around C and am pretty sick can't think too straight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression

```
*a.moo = 5;
```

it is supposed that the data member `moo` is a pointer that is dereferenced.

But actually it is `a` that is a pointer.

The postfix member access operator `.` has a higher precedence than the unary operator `*`.

So instead you need to write either

```
a->moo = 5;
```

or

```
( *a ).moo = 5;
```